# How to put html into js loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today I need help about How can I do a loop with html code and put the (i) value on the input name:

```
    <label>
       <input type='radio' class='parts' value='5' /> 5
    </label>
    <script>
    $(function(){

      jQuery('.parts').on('click', function(){
        var html = '';  
        for(i=1; i <= $(this).val(); i++ ){
          html += "<input type='text' name='cars[i]' /> car number i";
        }
        $('#result').html(html);
      });

    });
    </script>

<div id='result'></div>
```

If you dont undertand pls ask.

Comment: Your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/psyg36mx/. You should avoid putting the jQuery in the middle of your page if you're actually doing that.

Comment: What is the expected output and whats the error you're getting?

Comment: @PeterKA already help with that! look his answer, thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string concatenation:

```
html += "<input type='text' name='cars[" + i + "]' /> car number " + i;
```

```js
    $(function(){

      jQuery('.parts').on('click', function(){
        var html = '';  
        for(i=1; i <= $(this).val(); i++ ){
          html += "<input type='text' name='cars[" + i + "]' /> car number " + i + "<br>";
        }
        $('#result').html(html);
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
       <input type='radio' class='parts' value='5' /> 5
    </label>
<div id='result'></div>
```